# How to make an dictionary attack to a .p12 with password (educative pruposes)

Tags: security, encryption, public-key-encryption, dictionary-attack

Which programme or command do you use to extract the public key from a p12 protected with a password? I am trying with the command `hydra`but i think it only works along networks

Comment: John the Ripper password cracker

Answer (score 0):

You can use openssl to check, convert etc. a p12 file.

E.g.:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in example.p12
```

or

```
openssl pkcs12 -in example.p12 -out example.pem -nodes
```

etc.

You can make openssl read the password from a file or stdin. E.g.:

```
openssl [...] -pass stdin
```

See man page for openssl for more ideas.